# linking one column to another based on several conditions

Tags: r

I have a data frame named `df` with three variables. In my data, an identical ID number indicates that these people are of the same household. In column `age` Those who are 15 years old or older are parents (father or mother) and those who are under 15 are children. What I want is to link a child (Regardless of their gender) to only their mother (gender=2) based on mothers' age and finally count this child. In other words, I want to know how many children there are based on the age of their mothers. my expected output would be like df1 that columns 0,1,2,3 show the age of child.
thank you in advance.

```
df<- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,2,3,1,1), age=c(15,16,15,16,17,17,0,1,2,3,2,0), 
                gender=c(2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2))

df1<- 
age of mother   0  1  2  3 
15              1  0  0  0              
16              0  1  1  1
17              0  0  0  0
```

Comment: could you please clarify your desirable output?

Comment: in my expected output as shown in df1 child are linked to their mother based both mother and child age

Comment: How do you have only 4 child in the output when you have 6 in the data? `sum(df$age < 15)`

Comment: your desired output seems incorrect... in your sample data. no mopther has age 17, and there is one mothers (ID=1) of age 15 with 2 children of age 0.

Comment: @RonakShah some children have no mother in my data actually their mother do not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dcast(df[age >= 15 & gender == 2, ][df[age < 15,], on = .(ID)],
      age ~ i.age, fun.aggregate = length)

   age 0 1 2 3
1:  15 2 0 1 0
2:  16 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: when I run your code for my main data firs row of age of mother shows "NA"

Comment: then you probably have some (unwanted?) NA's in your data... you can exclude them if needed.